# Positive partial transposition for systems of more than 2 qubits?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Say we start with a 4-qubit pure state that does not satisfy the Peres-Horodecki criterion, i.e., its partial transposition has negative eigenvalues.

If I trace out one of its qubits, I will (most likely) end up with a mixed state of 3-qubits as a subsystem of the original pure state.

My question is, can this 3-qubit subsystem of the pure state be entangled, despite being PPT (positive partial transpose)?

Comment: How do you define "bound entangled" for tripartite systems?

Comment: I don't know how to define it, but I have read that a mixed tripartite system that is entangled and PPT, is a bound entangled state, since no entanglement can be distilled from it by local operations. I got this from the introduction in this paper (page 2): https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308032v3

Comment: Given that your question is not about the concepts themselves, you should be able to define them, rather than to refer to a paper.  (Otherwise, you are asking something involving things you already don't understand -- how do you expect to understand the answer?) Certainly, PPT for more than bi-partite states is a potentially ambiguous thing.

Comment: I don't see how pg 2 of that paper involves tripartite states, btw.

Comment: To be more specific, I was referring to this part: 

"(...) in higher dimensions, there are PPT
states that are nonetheless entangled (...) These states are called bound
entangled states because they have the peculiar property
that no entanglement can be distilled from them by local
operations."

I'm interested in having a criterion which can tell me directly if the density matrix of the subsystems of pure states is separable or not. Although the concept of bound entanglement is new to me, if the answer to my original question is simply "No", then the PPT criterion would be sufficient.

Comment: "Higher dimension" does mean $d_1\times d_2$, not tripartite.  Do you think of a state with one qubit and one $4$-level system?  Please edit *your post* (!) to clarify this!

Comment: You're right, I thought "Higher dimension" included three qubit systems ($2\times 2 \times 2$). I'll edit the question right away. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Despite your edit, it is still unclear what you mean by "entangled" and "PPT" for tri- and quadripartite states.